# When my Javascript should be executing... nothing happens

Tags: javascript, html, function

I'm creating a web push notification setup on my website, and honestly I've never had this issue javascript before that I'm encountering. Essentially what is happening here is that when javascript should be invoking the called method, nothing is happening. Not even a try-catch is catching an error.

`test.html`

Here is where I'm attempting to call the method from. If you will notice, in the `<head>` tag I referenced the js file that has the method.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="notify.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javscript">
            document.write("Test #1");
            try {
                document.write(sendUnsent()); 
                document.write("Test #2");
            } catch (error) {
                document.write(error);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

`notify.js`

This is where I'm attempting to call said function called `sendUnsent()`.

```
function sendUnsent()
{
    return "Hello world!";
}
```

My question is why is this script not executing and what possible fixes are there?

Comment: Are there any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">`

Comment: Are you seeing `Test #1` and `Test #2`?

Comment: [why document.write is bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice)

Comment: @Barmar I am not seeing Test 1 & Test 2. I left those in there to show there were tests made that were not showing.

Comment: @DanieleCappuccio There is nothing to be seen in the javscript console

Comment: It might be the misspelling of `javascript` in `text/javscript`. Either fix it or remove that attribute entirely, since Javascript is the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in the type of your `script` tag, it should be `text/javascript`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write("Test #1");
    try {
        document.write(sendUnsent()); 
        document.write("Test #2");
    } catch (error) {
        document.write(error);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for catching that! The fix works. I will accept as soon as I am able

Comment: The question should just be closed as a typo.

Comment: @Barmar, I don't know if I have the privilege to close it.

Comment: you don't, but we do.